# Setup URL redirection/rewrite for numbers

Tags: javascript, web, url, iis, url-rewriting

If I have a domain name like "example.com" hosted on IIS. How can I setup so any URL request with a numeric argument such as example.com/ would be redirected to for instance example.com/function/trigger/? (where "function/trigger" are hardcoded paths)

What is the way to do this? In my index.html, I could add a Javascript function that during load looks for a numeric parameter in the URL and then via javascript calls a redirect method. However, then the user needs to see/flicker the index.html before getting redirected. I would like that this is instant and not recognized that a redirected occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't clearly understand what you want to do, but I think it can be done by url rewrite, don't need to use javascript.

```
<rule name="rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^index/([0-9a-z]+)/([_0-9a-z]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/function/trigger" />
</rule>
```

It can match all url containing numeric argument, then redirect it to example.com/function/trigger/.

If I have any misunderstanding about your need, you can show me some sample url and redirected url so that I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really think thats kind of what I want. Where in IIS do I enter this rule? Example would be http://example.com/123 -> http://example.com/function/trigger/123

Comment: You can set url="/function/trigger" to url="/function/trigger/{R:1}/{R:2}"